# Dockerized API: cURL calls to self fail

Tags: php, docker, curl

I have a REST API that I am trying to move into a container. Everything works except calls to end points that utilize functionality of other end points.

When the end point tries to make a cURL call to one of the other API end points it fails.

For example:
I add items to a shopping cart then set the address. When the address is set the API sees it has enough information to get shipping quotes and calls the shipping quote end point. The connection times out and the original call returns an error since it was unable to get the shipping quotes.

If I call the shipping quote end point directly it works so it's not a problem with that end point. It only fails when using cURL to request the data from within a separate end point.

I'm not sure if this works in the wild since I'm just testing locally right now.

I suspect this has something to do with my local environment somehow. I ssh'd into the container and tested curl to make sure it is able to connect to things and it works just as it should. Also, the shipping quote end point uses curl to get the quotes from the service providers and that works as well.

I'm using:
Windows 10
Docker for Windows (17.09.1-ce-win42)

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: Should your API really be calling itself? You're going to be incurring overhead costs in your API if it's making multiple requests during one request, even if it's routed over the loopback interface. Can you not rewrite these endpoints to use the APIs internal methods instead of calling the external endpoints?

Comment: I'll be rewriting the entire API as microservices within the next year but for now I just want to get the entire thing in a container.

Comment: What IP address are you using and also how are your containers defined.

Comment: The IP is just the loopback IP. And I don't know how to answer your other question. I'm new to Docker. I've got the image up in an Azure repository and I'm using it in a docker compose file. I doubt that help answer it.